# Get Users from Active Directory Group

Tags: vb.net, active-directory

I have the below code to pull users from a particular security group from Active Directory (AD), interestingly it works for a one domain but doesnt work for another domain.
It always return nothing for variable "allResults " after doing a search.
Very strange, I really need advise.
I confirmed the AD group and its present with users in there,user credentials to login to AD is correct
For the two domains that worked they were like xxx.com, but the one that didnt work its like xxx.local.Could that be the issue?

```
Dim myLdapConnection As New DirectoryEntry(ADServer, ADUser, ADPwd)
        Dim search As New DirectorySearcher(myLdapConnection, "(objectCategory=group)")

        With search
            .Filter = "sAMAccountName=" & ApproveGroup
            .PropertiesToLoad.Add("member")
        End With
        'a = "sAMAccountName=" & ApproveGroup
        '("(objectClass=user)")
        Dim strUsers As String
        Dim intEqualsIndex As Integer
        Dim intCommaIndex As Integer

        search.CacheResults = True
        Dim allResults As SearchResult = search.FindOne
        If IsNothing(allResults) Then
            lblresponse.Text = "No member exists in this group (" & ApproveGroup & ")"
            lblresponse.Visible = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
```